# ASCII character problem on mac. Can't print the black square(which is char(219))

Tags: c++, macos, char, ascii

When I'm trying to do this code in C++

```
cout << char(219);
```

the output on my mac is question mark  ?
However, on PC it gives me a black square.
Does anyone have any idea why on mac there is only 128 characters, when it should be 256?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your post appears broken, possibly due to the special characters in your code. To post a block of code, indent it by four spaces. To post code in the middle of normal text, add a backtick (`) to the start and end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no such thing as [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character 219.  ASCII only goes up to 127.  chars 128-255 are defined in different ways in different character encodings for different languages and different OSs.

- [MacRoman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Roman) defines it as `€`.
- [IBM code page 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) (used at the Windows command prompt) defines it as `█`.
- [Windows code page 1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) (used in Windows GUI programs) defines it as `Û`.
- [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) defines it as a *part* of a 2-byte character.  (Specifically, the lead byte of the characters [U+06C0 to U+06FF](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0600.pdf).)

Comment: And your `std::locale` will determine which of these apply. You may be able to switch locales, but the list of alternative locales is platform-dependent.

Answer (score 2):

ASCII is really a 7-bit encoding. If you are printing char(219) that is using some other encoding: on Windows most probably CP 1252. On Mac, I have no idea...

Answer (score 1):

When a character is missing from an encoding set, it shows a box on Windows (it's not character 219, which doesn't exist) Macs show the question mark in a diamond symbol because a designer wanted it that way. But they both mean the same thing, missing/invalid character.

Comment: You are wrong. try to compile this program and you will see all the different characters: 'for(int i = 0; i<256; i++) cout<<i<<"  = "<<char(i)<<endl;'

Comment: Well the question mark that is shows in OS X is a diamond with a question in it not just a question mark right?